# Theos - How to call instance methods from a different class

Tags: ios, objective-c, cydia, theos, cydia-substrate

Basically what I'm trying to do is call the `attemptDeviceUnlockWithPassword` method from `SBDeviceLockScreenViewController`'s `lockScreenView` method. What is the proper way to call an instance method from a different class?

```
%hook SBLockScreenViewController

-(void)lockScreenView:(id)view didScrollToPage:(int)page
{
    if (page==0)
    {
    //call attemptDeviceUnlockWithPassword:@"0000" appRequested:NO
    }
    %orig;
}

%end

%hook SBDeviceLockController

- (BOOL)attemptDeviceUnlockWithPassword:(NSString *)passcode appRequested:(BOOL)requested
{

    return %orig;

}

%end
```

Comment: I think you need to learn the basics of objective-c first, try the tag's wiki.

Answer (score 3):

In order to be able to call an instance method you need an instance of a class. You can see from the [SBDeviceLockController header](http://developer.limneos.net/?framework=SpringBoard&header=SBDeviceLockController.h) that there is a class method `+(id)sharedController`. This method will return an instance which you can call instance methods on.

There are quite a few classes in SpringBoard that follow this pattern of having a class method return the a singleton instance (this is called the [Singleton pattern](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/)).

You need to learn more about the basics of Objective-C before doing tweak development, try just creating a simple app. The Apple documentation is pretty good ([try starting here)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html), and there are many other resources on the internet (such as the [Stanford CS193P course](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/)).